# how to find html elements in data property in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to make a form something like yoast which it will check how many `<h1>` or `<img>` exist in data or how many `<img>` tag got alt attribute...

Currently i'm using [Vue Quill Editor](https://github.surmon.me/vue-quill-editor/) for my code editor and i'm getting my html elements in my data, here's a simple setup :

Vue :

```
<template>
    <quill-editor
        class="editor"
        ref="myTextEditor"
        :value="postForm.postBody"
        @change="onEditorChange($event)"
    />
</template>
<script>
    import dedent from "dedent";

    export default {
        name: "post_detail",
        props: ['postForm'],
        methods: {
            onEditorChange({ quill, html, text }) {
                this.postForm.postBody = html
            }
        },
        computed: {
            editor() {
                return this.$refs.myTextEditor.quill
            }
        },
    }

</script>
```

so everything is working fine with this setup. now i want to add some text below this form to report for example how many `<img>` tag exist in data or how many `<img>` tag got attribute or something like this.

Edit 01: Data property will get exactly html elements like `<h1>Hello</h1><img src="./img.jpg" alt="data">`

Comment: I don't think you would be able to do this in vue directly since quill is not a native vue thingy. You'll probably need to do this manually in plain js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is create a temporary DOM from that html string then use something like `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByTagName` to count it.

```js
...
  methods: {
    onEditorChange({ quill, html, text }) {
      let root = document.createElement('div')
      root.innerHTML = html
      this.h1Count = root.querySelectorAll('h1').length
    }
  }
...
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3g4avf0h/)